# Simple document/file management software

Tags: linux, web-applications, version-control, document-management

I'm looking for a simple way to share documents/files with other people via a web-based interface. The requirements are the following:

- runs on Linux
- web-based download/upload
- versioning
- basic authorization (users/groups)
- free

The enduser-visible interface should be as simple as possible, I don't want to confuse the non-technical users.

Answer (score 2):

In our office [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) is "simple" and very useful,

You can try it [here](http://www.alfresco.com/try/).

You can get the Community version [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_Community_Edition).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it but I was looking for something smaller. Alfresco seems like overkill for my modest needs.

Comment: I had a look at Alfresco and it definitely can do everything I need but it is about an order of magnitude too powerful. I'm really looking for a limited software that is easy to set up. This is an academic environment, we don't have a dedicated sysadmin, all server stuff is done on the side by PhD students.